# How to Optimize a aggregate SQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Assume a table schema like:

```
name amount_1, amount_2, cond_1, cond_2
```

the table have 500,000+rows.

How to optimize query like:

```
select 
  name
  , sum(amount_1) as total_1
  , sum(amount_2) as total_2
  , sum(amount_1+amount_2) as total 
from table_name 
where cond_1 in ('a', 'b') 
group by name 
order by total desc 
limit 10;
```

Current the sql will take minutes to run.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `name`, and `cond_1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely to be missing indexes on these columns:

- `name` for the grouping
- `cond_1` for the filtering

If you prefer to have a compound index only, I recommend making that an index on `(cond_1, name)` (not the other way round). Why? `cond_1` should be the first column in the compound index as the filter predicate can profit only from the columns on the left of an index.

This is explained here, for instance:
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Answer (score 1):

Indexing will help, plus you can rewrite the query slightly:

```
SELECT
  s.*, s.total_1 + s.total_2 AS total
FROM (
  SELECT
    name
    , SUM(amount_1) as total_1
    , SUM(amount_2) as total_2
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE cond_1 in ('a', 'b') 
  GROUP BY name ) s
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This will prevent a sum of (total_1 + total_2) over all the rows, but instead reuse the totals calculated in `total_1` and `total_2`.

You can also try this variant, which may be slower or faster :-).
If you have an index on amount1 and amount2 and a substantial, but not huge fraction is 0 this may be much faster.

```
SELECT
  s.*, s.total_1 + s.total_2 AS total
FROM (
  SELECT
    name
    , SUM(amount_1) as total_1
    , SUM(amount_2) as total_2
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE cond_1 in ('a', 'b') AND (amount_1 <> 0 AND amount_2 <> 0)
  GROUP BY name ) s
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

If you have lots of stuff in the `IN`, it may be faster to do

```
WHERE cond_1 BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'
```

This exchanges 26 OR tests for 2 AND tests.

Comment: Why does a `not equal` test result in a full table scan, that sounds like nonsense to me! I agree that under most datasets the test will be slower, but `always a full table scan` is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

Except indexes metioned by Lukas Eder, I suppose that one of `sum`'s is unnecessary, because if `amount_1` and `amount_2` are `NOT NULL` then you will have equation

total = total_1 + total_2

So, if you need `total` for ordering, you can loose total_2 and calculate it after query execution as (total - total_1)

Don't know if it save you much time, but looks like a little optimisation for me.

Comment: That depends on how many grouping results there are... If there are many distinct `name`'s then you're probably right

Comment: Actually it's better to use `(sum(amount_1)+sum(amount_2)) as total`

Answer (score 0):

if this is an important part of your business consider OLAP, it's the faster way I know